# TTTAttributedLabel clickable truncation token

Tags: ios, uilabel, tttattributedlabel

I have a TTTAttributedLabel and specified a custom attributed truncation token for it:

```
NSAttributedString *atributedTruncationToken = [[[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                                     initWithString:@" More..."
                                                         attributes:@{
                                                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                                                                      NSFontAttributeName : self.messageLabel.font,
                                                                      NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType // no effect
                                                                      }] autorelease];

  [self.messageLabel setAttributedTruncationToken:atributedTruncationToken];
```

It looks perfect, but how can I make the token clickable?

(Particularly, I need the label to expand when user clicks on the token, but not on the rest of the label).

**UPDATE.**
As I have found out, it is possible (iOS 7+) to add a link to the token, like the follows:

```
NSAttributedString *atributedTruncationToken = [[[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                                     initWithString:@" More..."
                                                         attributes:@{
                                                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                                                                      NSFontAttributeName : self.messageLabel.font,
                                                                      NSLinkAttributeName : [NSURL URLWithString:@"..."]
                                                                      }] autorelease];
```

But there is kind of a bug (?) in TTTAttributed label, that the token still does not became clickable, but the n (`n = token length`) last characters of the label's text do!

Comment: i am also facing the same problem. Truncated text is not clickable instead the last few characters get clicked.Do you solve this problem,if yes please let me know.

Comment: Nope, I did not even try. I just implemented my own clumsy label, using CoreText, UIButton and delegate. If it is possible, use newer version of TTTAttributedLabel.

Comment: in newer version also i am facing the same problem..sometime it is clickable if the truncated token is at the end table row.but if comes in between of row, then it is not working

Answer (score 0):

[ResponsiveLabel](https://github.com/hsusmita/ResponsiveLabel/), a subclass of UILabel can be used to configure clickable truncation token.

```
NSString *expansionToken = @"Read More ...";
NSString *str = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
NSMutableAttributedString *attribString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:kExpansionToken attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor],NSFontAttributeName:self.customLabel.font}];
[self.customLabel setAttributedTruncationToken:attribString withAction:^(NSString *tappedString) {
  NSLog(@"Tap on truncation text");
}];
[self.customLabel setText:str withTruncation:YES];
```

Comment: I tried [ResponsiveLabel](https://github.com/hsusmita/ResponsiveLabel/), and in the demo project I have very weird scrolling issues on expanding the label in a table view.